# How to start Seaborn Logarithmic Barplot at y=1

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, logging, seaborn, bar-chart

I have a problem figuring out how to have Seaborn show the right values in a logarithmic barplot. A value of mine should be, in the ideal case, be 1. My dataseries (5,2,1,0.5,0.2) has a set of values that deviate from unity and I want to visualize these in a logarithmic barplot. However, when plotting this in the standard log-barplot it shows the following:

[image: Wrong plot]

But the values under one are shown to increase from -infinity to their value, whilst the real values ought to look like this:

[image: Right plot, Excel]

Strangely enough, I was unable to find a Seaborn, Pandas or Matplotlib attribute to "snap" to a different horizontal axis or "align" or ymin/ymax. I have a feeling I am unable to find it because I can't find the terms to shove down my favorite search engine. Some semi-solutions I found *just* did not match what I was looking for or did not have either xaxis = 1 or a ylog. A try that uses some jank Matplotlib lines:

[image: Right-ish]

If someone knows the right terms or a solution, thank you in advance.

Here are the Jupyter cells I used:

{1}

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'X': ['A','B','C','D','E'], 'Y': [5,2,1,0.5,0.2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

{2}

```
%matplotlib widget
g = sns.catplot(data=df, kind="bar", y = "Y", x = "X", log = True)
```

{3}

```
%matplotlib widget
plt.vlines(x=data['X'], ymin=1, ymax=data['Y'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could let the bars start at 1 instead of at 0. You'll need to use `sns.barplot` directly.

The example code subtracts 1 of all y-values and sets the bar `bottom` at `1`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'X': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'Y': [5, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
ax = sns.barplot(y=df["Y"] - 1, x=df["X"], bottom=1, log=True, palette='flare_r')
ax.axhline(y=1, c='k')

# change the y-ticks, as the default shows too few in this case
ax.set_yticks(np.append(np.arange(.2, .8, .1), np.arange(1, 7, 1)), minor=False)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(.3, 6, .1), minor=True)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda x, pos: f'{x:.0f}' if x >= 1 else f'{x:.1f}')
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(NullFormatter())
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], labels=df["Y"])
sns.despine()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.barplot with logscale starting at 1]

PS: With these specific values, the plot might go without logscale:

[image: sns.barplot starting at 1, no logscale]

Comment: The weekend has ended and thus work starts again.
Wow, that is a lot of code to fix something that could be interpreted as undefined behavior. Strange that Excel of all things does this automatically but you have to use a hack to be able to redefine the baseline of the bars. Anyways, this perfectly solves my problem so thank you very much!
P.S.: the Y value is a symmetry quotient, so a symmetry of 1 means the left and right are equal, but 2 and 0.5 are equally bad (2:1 and 1:2); hence why I needed a log scale, so that these two values appear equally bad.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. It makes a lot of sense. 
Maybe the y-axis should be labelled with the inverses? Like `2^-1`,  `3^-1`, ...?

Comment: I will likely use an "Arbitrary scale" for the Y-axis, so this is not a huge issue.

Comment: Another small note since it took me some time to figure out what was wrong: if you want to add custom ticks and attach custom yticklabels to the solution provided by JohanC, you need to add this AFTER the NullFormatter line, otherwise the ytickmarks get overridden.